# What can I do such that processing the logic of the left pane using servlet, the output is shown in the right pane of the same html file?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

It is an html document. The page is divided into vertical partitions. There are text boxes in the in the left pane (input pane). They are to be processed and the output is to be shown in the right pane (output pane; using iframe). I have created the business logic, using java servlet to fetch the values from the text boxes and processing them. All these are done in java. All I could do was to display the output using servlet *out.print("html_tags")* in a different window. But I wish to display the output in the same html file in the right pane.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please add all of your code.

Comment: Use Ajax to call the servlet and JQuery or just plain Javascript to put the result where you want.